# Created SOAP Service Reference in .NET using WSDL. The proxy class doesn't seem to expose the SOAP response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm writing a Web Service in ASP.NET/C# (.NET 4.6, VS 2015) that needs to:

1. receive XML data,
2. parse the XML data,
3. use parsed data to call a separate SOAP Service,
4. receive the response from the SOAP service,
5. manipulate the response from the SOAP service, and
6. send the manipulated XML back to the calling
   application

I'll admit I'm brand new at writing Web services. 1-3 are done. 5-6 will be trivial as I'm already sending back a "Hello World" type response back to the calling application.

I'm stuck at #4. The response envelope seems nowhere to be found -- there is no error calling the external SOAP service, this same SOAP call with the same data sends a response with using Fiddler and Postman, so the external SOAP service is fine.

With regards to #4, I have added a Service Reference to the existing SOAP service. I'm able to call the Web Service, but in debugging and looking through the proxy class, I don't see any way to access the response envelope, or anything inside the response envelope.

I know this is extremely basic so there must be something I'm missing. Is there a tutorial someone can point me to? I have been searching for a solution for days with no joy.

Do I need to edit the Service Reference to return data? If so, how would I do this?

Sorry again for the newbie question; thank you so much in advance.

**Summary**: The SOAP service I'm calling works and responds properly, but I can't find how to actually retrieve data from the SOAP response envelope; I don't even see the SOAP response envelope anywhere when debugging. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.

---

**EDIT:** Here is some code requested earlier with further explanation:

```
string fieldValue = _fieldPrefix + fieldContents + _fieldSuffix;  

ExternalSoapClient soapClient = new ExternalSoapClient(_endpointName);
soapClient.Execute(fieldValue);  

ExecuteResponseBody responseBody = new ExecuteResponseBody();  
string executeResult = responseBody.ExecuteResult;
```

I suppose the question I'm asking is: **I'm fairly certain I'm missing a step connecting the response with the execution**. The SOAP method is called "Execute" with only the one string field shown above.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't access the SOAP response envelope directly via WCF.  The methods will return a type (either a simple type like string or int or a complex type) that is deserialized into the underlying .NET type (i.e., for a string, you'll get a string, for a complex type you'll get a class).  Can you post some code and some examples of what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for responding Tim, please see my edits at the end of OP above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish in the code sample, but I *think* what you're looking for is something like this:

```
string fieldValue = _fieldPrefix + fieldContents + _fieldSuffix;  

ExternalSoapClient soapClient = new ExternalSoapClient(_endpointName);
ExecuteResponseBody responseBody = soapClient.Execute(fieldValue);  

string executeResult = responseBody.ExecuteResult;
```

What I would expect is that `Execute` returns a `ExecuteResponseBody` object that is represented as a class in the .NET framework.  The `ExecuteResult` property on that class should contain the value you're looking for.

In a nutshell, your code should assign the response from the service to the `ExecuteResponseBody` object, and then you can access the data contained therein.   Your current approach is not connecting the `ExecuteResponseBody` object to the result of the service call - you're creating a new object *after* the call (and doing nothing with the result returned from the call), so the data you're looking for will not be in the newly created object.

Comment: Tim, I think you're on the right track, and the disconnect between the two objects is what I was trying to resolve, so thank you. The issue is that the **Execute** method returns a string rather than an ExecuteResponseBody, and that string is null.

Comment: When you mouse over `soapClient.Execut`, what does intellisense say the return type is?  If it's a string, then simply do `string executeResult = soapClient.Execute(fieldValue);`.

Comment: OK, thank you, makes sense. I actually had already tried this but got a null string... I think a new issue may have come up just today (wasn't doing it yesterday when testing with Postman/Fiddler) with the web service returning simply <ExecuteResult /> with no data. My unfamiliarity with writing a Web Service client made me doubt myself. I guess when that issue is resolved, I'll know if your suggestion works. For now I'll mark it as "Answered" and will post again if it turns out there's something else I can't figure out. Thanks!

Comment: When I debug and copy the value of "fieldValue" into a SOAP Envelope in Postman, I'm now getting values inside the "executeResult" XML field, so that issue is now resolved. Unfortunately in my service, soapClient.Execute(fieldValue) is still returning an empty ("") string. Very strange.